# $G^2$ outerplanar implies $G$ is triangle or path

Tags: graph-theory

Definition: Let $G$ be a connected graph. The square $G^2$ of graph $G$ is the graph with $V(G^2)=V(G)$ such that $uv$ is an edge of $G^2$ if $ 1 \leq \text{dist}(u,v) \leq 2$.

(a)Prove that if $G^2$ is outerplanar the $G$ is a triangle or a path.

(b) Describe the class of graphs such that $G^2$ is planar.

.........................................................

This is not a homework. I am studying for an exam.

Any help?

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 1):

for (a), i think you could use the fact that an outer-planar graph contains no $K_4$ minors to  show that there is not a vertex of degree 3 in the original graph first and this implies that the graph $G$ is either a cycle or a path. Then argue that the only case for being a cycle is the triangle. Cheers !